# Need your suggestion with conversion

Tags: asp.net

We having a VB6 Windows Application and now user wants to convert this with latest C# Asp.net/Asp.Net MVC application.

If Asp.net Web application is not possible, then we can opt for C# winform application.

My question what are the migration tools available and what are the challenges in conversion.

Please suggest?

Comment: That's not possible, you have to rewrite from scratch.

Comment: that i understand Web is not quite possible...OK is there any way/tool to convert it into C# winform application....?please suggest....

Comment: VB6 and .NET development model doesn't match. conversation is not possible

Comment: Please see this, http://www.artinsoft.com/    now your comment please?

Comment: If you're willing to pay thousands of dollars to get it converted instead of easy migration by yourself, go for it. :)

Comment: @walther that thousands of dollars obiously goes from client pocket :) :)...anyway nice comment to show to my client....

Answer (score 2):

Even if there was such a tool (and I'm 99,99% sure there's not), DO NOT USE IT. Such automated conversions are never a good idea. Rewrite the app from scratch instead, you'll end up with a much better code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any GOOD conversion tools that will do all the work for you, and indeed you wouldn't want to. Web/MVC apps work in a completely different way to WinForms apps. For converting to a C# WinForm app you'd need to do that manually as well.

Without knowing anything about what the app does, I couldn't say whether you could make it a web app, but in theory it's possible. I've migrated form apps to web based apps in the past without any problems. But I did have to do it myself rather than use a tool.